# Input button does not work in Wordpress (Bootstrap)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, submit

I'm new in PHP. I'm trying to make a small plugin for Wordress using Bootstrap styles. The problem is that the submit input element within the form does not work (it's not clickable) until the form is wrapped in `<td></td>` tags. Then it becomes functional (see the code below).

```
<?php   wp_register_script('prefix_bootstrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('prefix_bootstrap'); 
?>

<div class="">
<h3>Test</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-7"
<td>
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-7">
<label for="va_weight">Weight:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="va_weight" id="va_weight" placeholder="Weight, kg" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-7">
    <label for="inputquantity">Number:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="va_quantity" id="inputquantity" placeholder="Number, pcs ">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-7">
    <label for="inputcost">Cost:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="va_cost" id="inputcost" placeholder="Cost ">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-alert" value="Submit"></input>
      </br></br></br></br></br></br>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</td>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5"> <?php
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ?? 'GET')=='POST'&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo ("Your weight:" ." " .$_POST["va_weight"] ."</br>");
echo ("Number of measurements:" ." " .$_POST["va_quantity"] ."</br>");
echo ("Cost per measurement:" ." " .$_POST["va_cost"]);
}
else 
{echo ("Nothing to display");}
?></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Could anybody explain what's going on? Why the input does not work without `<td>`?

Comment: You forgot the closing ">" at line 8: <div class="col-sm7"

Comment: Thank you! I've fixed and the input start working! But i'm still wondering... how does the mistake in html that is not associated with input itself influence on its functionality?

Comment: check the answer i posted for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, the missing closing ">" is messing the html so you can't submit a form. This is why:

Initially you said that you can't submit the form unless you wrap it into a "td". By missing the closing tag, the html rendered by the browser does not catch the form tag. It only parses the html like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-7" form method="post" action="">
<!-- 
I specifically removed the "<" so you will see it better. 
With this html, there is no form, only a div with multiple attributes. 
-->
```

Wrapping the form with `td` helps you because the closing tag of the `td` closes the `div`.

```
<div class="col-sm-7" td > 
<!-- 
I missed the "<" again so you could understand better.
The closing tag of the "td" is in fact closing the "div"
which makes the html form valid and the button will in fact submit the form.
-->
<form method="post" action="">
...
</form>
```

Even with the "hack" you used for making the form work, your html is still not valid because you now have an extra closing `</td>` at the end which is closing nothing.

You can remove the `td` when you correctly close the `div`.